# How to wait for a system command to execute using ruby script

Tags: ruby, batch-file

I have used system method to run a bat file, the bat file opens and run successfully but my execution wont stop until my bat file has completed its execution

I tried several method like system, exec but nothing is working as I expected. I am new to ruby. I want to be able to stop my execution until my bat file has completed its execution.

Code:
system('path/to/file.bat')

Answer (score 0):

From what I know `system` is using a subshell and waits for the called command to be fully executed to continue execution of the caller script.

I just executed the following code locally:

```rb
require 'time'
puts Time.now; system('sleep 5'); puts Time.now
# result:
# 2023-02-03 11:44:19 +0100
# 2023-02-03 11:44:24 +0100
```

And as you can see there is 5 seconds between the first `Time.now` call and the second one, so the calling process waited fo the `system` to finish the execution before printing the time again.

Maybe the behavior is different on windows. Would you mind to try locally and share the result ?